# Change StatusBar color of PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, mobile

Setting activity:
[image: Setting activity]

This is setting Activity and it includes Preference Category.
When I click folder option, then it goes to Preference Fragment.

Preference fragment:
[image: Preference Fragment]

As you can see, status bar color changed from WHITE.

But I have to keep WHITE color.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    implements OnPreferenceClickListener, OnPreferenceChangeListener {

private SecurityHelper securityHelper;
private Preference preference;

public SettingsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));

    int nightModeFlags = DocumentsApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;

    if(nightModeFlags == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
    else if(nightModeFlags == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I tried this, but not success, How can I fix status bar Color?

Answer (score 0):

[image: values folder]

You can define style for the whole application for both lite and night mode.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't help for me. I solve it by myself. I defined nestedPreference functions for under tree of preference category. I changed statusbar programmatically in this function and it works for me.